# Cannot connect to MongoDB while using public network

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I cannot connect the MongoDB server in my Discord bot project, using nodejs framework. Below is the error:

> MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/

I in fact had allowed all IP addresses, which I put 0.0.0.0 at the whitelist. Which shows:

```
0.0.0.0/0  (includes your current IP address)
```

I only had that problem when I am using my college network, while this issue does not occur when I am using my own network (Mobile / Home). Therefore, I can believe that is not my code and approach issue. Does anyone know how to fix it? Or does it limit the access from public network?

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Bobosky It looks like your college firewall not allowing mongodb port. The default port is 27017. You can reach out to the network administrator to whitelist the inbound and outbound traffic from this port. This will solve your problem